# Wordpress: Post has no formatting

Tags: wordpress, formatting

I've just begun learning to develop WordPress themes, and I'm developing my first theme, but I have an issue, where the formatting set in the Visual Editor isn't used when displaying a post...

So, my code is as follows:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: News
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="contentWrap">
        <div id="content">

        <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $query = array (
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'paged' => $paged,
                'cat' => 4
                );
            query_posts ($query); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <em>Posted on:</em> <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </article>                
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <div class="navigation">
                <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
                <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
            </div>

            <?php else : ?>
            <h2>Not found</h2>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end contentWrap -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So the issue is, if I create a post and set some formatting (bold, italics, etc.), the post is still shown as plain text with no formatting except line breaks... I'm guessing the issue is related to how I get the post, but as I'm completely new in WordPress, I haven't been able to find the solution...

What am I missing?

Comment: Can I get your post url?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with how you're getting the content.  Have you done a CSS reset without redefining some of the basic tags like em and strong?

Comment: Deminoth Bono - I can't share a link to my site or post, as I'm developing locally until the site is fully developed... Chris Herbert, I followed a WordPress theme development tutorial, so I've written the CSS from scratch and included some WordPress core stuff... Is there something that needs to be included for the formatting to appear?

Comment: Did you add a CSS reset?  If not, the formatting should appear.  What theme have you used as a base?  Many include a reset.  In any case, if we can't see your site, or at least your css, we can't help you.